# Selected duplicate words removing in a sentence through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, duplicates

I want to remove some words which start with @ in the sentence which are duplicated in javascript how can I achieve it.
For example:

```
"This is @banker does banking in a @bank, this @banker is good."
```

Here in this sentence, I want to remove the extra word "@banker" from it.

1. How can I do it in javascript?
2. Consider every word that should be removed will start with "@"

Comment: First you try something. Then we help if you have a problem.

Comment: I tried to split and able to get the duplicates removed but all duplciates are getting removed. thats the problem. I want to remove duplicates that starts only with @.

Comment: That will change the meaning of the sentence.  `", this is good"` = it's good that the banking is in a bank (this = banking), while `", this banker is good"` = the banker themselves are good at what they do (this = the banker).

Comment: Here the sentence is just an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```js
const text = 'This is @banker does banking in a @bank, this @banker is good.';
const splittedWords = text.split(' ');

let newSentence = [];

splittedWords.forEach(word => {
    if (word.startsWith('@')) {
        if (newSentence.indexOf(word) === -1) {
            newSentence.push(word);
        }
    } else {
        newSentence.push(word);
    }
});

console.log(newSentence.join(' '));
```

**UPDATE**

```js
const text = 'This is @2, this is @3, this is @2';
const splittedWords = text.split(' ');

let newSentence = [];

splittedWords.forEach(word => {
    if (word.startsWith('@')) {
        cleanedSentence = newSentence.map(word => word.replace(/,/g, ''));
        cleanedWord = word.replace(/,/g, '');
        if (cleanedSentence.indexOf(cleanedWord) === -1) {
            newSentence.push(word);
        }
    } else {
        newSentence.push(word);
    }
});

console.log(newSentence.join(' '));
```

Comment: This is good, it is working for alphabets but not for numbers as well like "This is @2, this is @3, this is @2" its is not removing complete duplicate(@2) it just removes @ from the duplicate returns(2). example for previous sentence: "This is @2, this is @3, this is 2"

Comment: @RohitGowda it's not a problem of `type`. The problem is that they are different strings (because of the comma) `@2,` and `@2`. I'm updating the answer.